# What is the highest accuracy of the Stanford's Large Movie Review Dataset ever achieved?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, imdb

I want to know the NLP model that was able to achieve the highest accuracy using the open Stanford's Large Movie Review Dataset, and also its accuracy.
The link to the [dataset](https://ai.stanford.edu/%7Eamaas/data/sentiment/).

Answer (score 1):

I think [this research](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/1550/3/032056/meta) may provide you with an answer.This paper uses Stanford's IMDb dataset (Stanford's Large Movie
Review Dataset) as the dataset for text sentiment classification. it says more info and
CNN-BLSTM-Attention 0.99 accuracy has been reported.